# Installing Elementary OS on a MacBook Pro 13" Early 2011 (8,1)

Tags: system-installation, macintosh, elementary-os

I'm trying to install elementaryOS (which is based on Ubuntu 10.10) on my MacBook Pro 13" Early 2011 (model No 8,1). I have resized a partition on my hard drive, and I've installed refit. Two things I've noticed:

1. refit doesn't notice the optical Drive, however pressing <kbd>c</kbd> allows me to boot the CD.
2. When I try to install or "try" the OS, I always end up with the following message:

   > `(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live filesystem`
3. I think these two things are connected - perhaps the OS isn't giving access to the optical drive somehow?

Comment: `(initramfs) unable to find a medium containing a live filesystem` looks like it could be an error with the live CD.

Comment: I used a different CD and downloaded the image from bittorrent, I still get this error.

Comment: Same set of problems here. Also, I cannot launch AHT to check hardware.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in this versions of MacBook Pro, you have to boot with both boot devices i.e. you have to boot with the CD and with the bootable pendrive as well on the computer. Keep doing what you did, but with a pen with elementary OS Jupiter on it as well and you won't have problems.

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm using a live pen created with unetbootin. Do you have any idea? Is it necessary a cd?